# Virtual MouseButtonEventHandler in my DLL overridden from calling application

Tags: wpf, events, overriding, virtual

I have my class library, which dynamic create label in grid

```
public class Class1
{
        public virtual event System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler label_event;

        public Class1(Grid _grid)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Content = "label";
            l.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Hand;
            Grid.SetColumn(_grid, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(_grid, 0);
            _grid.Children.Add(l);

            l.MouseLeftButtonUp += label_event;
        }
}
```

From another application this class is created

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1(grid);
class1.label_event += l_MouseLeftButtonUp;
...
void l_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
       Title = sender.ToString();
}
...
```

Compiling is without errors, but after executing there is an error in **l.MouseLeftButtonUp += label_event;** "Cannot be null"

How can i override mouse event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should raise an event in `Class1` and then handle it in the consuming class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public event System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler label_event;

    public Class1(Grid _grid)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        l.Content = "label";
        l.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Hand;
        Grid.SetColumn(_grid, 0);
        Grid.SetRow(_grid, 0);
        _grid.Children.Add(l);

        l.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s,e) => label_event?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, but this code is not compiled for me, but this is ok l.MouseLeftButtonUp += (s, e) => { if (label_event != null) label_event.Invoke(s, e); };